# Bash shell: How to reformat string date from a variable value

Tags: bash, shell, date, variables

I understand how to reformat a date using the `date` command, and I am fine with that.  However, I have a wrinkle in that I am struggling with - the date I want to reformat is the output of another command, so I am storing it in the variable.  I am struggling with the syntax of how to specify that I want to take the output of one command, and run it through `date -d`, and store it in another variable.  Here is what I tried:

```
expdate=`get_expire_date.sh`
echo $expdate
Mon 23 Mar 2022 05:05:05 PM UTC
expdval=`date -d'($expdate)'`
echo $expdval
```

I get today's date, not the converted expire date from the script output.  If I leave the parenthesis out, of course, it treats $expdate as the literal text to translate and gives an error, whereas if I leave the single quote marks off, it uses the spaces in the date string as a delimiter and only grabs the first token.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add output of `get_expire_date.sh` to your question.

Comment: `expdval=$(date -d"$expdate")` (assuming `$expdate` is in a format understood by `date` - which gets back to Cyrus' question about the output from `get_expire_date.sh`)

Comment: @Fravadona, No, `date -d` does not take a filename as an argument. Process substitutions look like files (such as `echo <(pwd)`)

Comment: Oops, my bad: `echo "$(date -d "$(./get_expire_date.sh)")"`

Comment: Also take into account that the meaning of `-d` changes on different platforms

Comment: Example output of `get_expire_date.sh`:    `Wed Mar 23 2022 05:05:05 PM UTC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, parameter expansion doesn't occur inside single quotes. You would need to change the single quotes

```
expdval=`date -d'($expdate)'`
```

to double quotes

```
expdval=`date -d"($expdate)"`
```

Second, the parentheses create an invalid input, which results (for reasons I don't really understand) in an output of midnight of the current day. (You'll get the same result with the trivial invalid date `date -d ""`.)

Drop the parentheses, and you'll get the same date back (because the input format matches the default output format).

```
$ date -d "$expdate"
Wed Mar 23 13:05:05 EDT 2022
```

To actually manipulate it, you'll need an explicit output format:

```
$ date -d "$expdate" +%Y-%m-%d
2022-03-23
```

or some form of date "arithmetic":

```
$ date -d "$expdate + 2 days"
Fri Mar 25 13:05:05 EDT 2022
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to use double-quotes instead, like this (and sorry for the old way of doing things, updating to new shell syntax):

```
expdval=$(date -d"$(get_expire_date.sh)")
```

Comment: "new shell syntax" that's been around since about 1990!